# Python - Group by > sample from every group

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with over 40.000 rows, where a certain column denotes the group membership. There are eight groups.
I would like to have a smaller DataFrame, where I sample an *x* number from each group.

```
allthedata.groupby("groupvariable", group_keys=False).apply(lambda group_df: group_df.sample(100, random_state=784))
```

With the code above I sample 100 cases per group. However, I would like to sample 10 from group 1, 40 from group 2, 10 from group 3 etc. This is not relative to the total group size.

Is there some way I can specify how much to sample per group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think in this case a for loop is necessary:

```
groups = ["groupvariable", "groupvariable2", "groupvariable3" ...]
sample_sizes = [100, 40, 10, ...]

# initialise list of dataframes samples to concatenate     
samples = []

for group, sample_size in zip(groups, sample_sizes):

       samples.append(allthedata.groupby(group, group_keys=False).sample(sample_size, random_state=784)) 

# concatenate all samples into unique data frame 
final_df = pd.concat(samples)
```

Comment: But actually I only have one grouping variable. Then I still can't figure it out

Comment: I got an error; DataFrameGroupby does not have the attribute sample. So I did it like this;  
`for group, sample_size in zip(groups, sample_sizes):`  
    `samples.append(allthedata.groupby(group, group_keys=False).apply(lambda group_df: group_df.sample(sample_size, random_state=784))) `

Comment: Glad that you managed to fix it. And sorry for the typos, I just wrote some code to give you the gist of the right direction to follow. Next time consider to put a piece of example of your data frame in your question, so it will be easier for people to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, thanks to Edoardo Guerriero and some small changes:

```
groups = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

sample_sizes = [1, 30, 70, 1, 5, 40, 20, 70]

samples = []

for group, sample_size in zip(groups, sample_sizes):

        samples.append(allthedata.groupby("groupingvar").get_group(group).sample(sample_size, random_state=4465))

# concatenate all samples into unique data frame 

finaldf = pd.concat(samples)
```